# Risk of asynchronously assigning a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, synchronization

There are many stackoverflow questions related to (a)synchronous executions and promises, but I did not quite find an answer to this.

Imagine I have the following:

```
var number = 0;
someAsyncFunctionWithCallback(function(){
    number++;
});
// ^ execute the above multiple times
```

As the execution times of each call of the function varies, the callbacks will be called at different times. Therefore, I am wondering what the behavior of the variable-incrementing line will be. In Java, I can declare variables as `synchronous` such that every increment will be taken into account. With the code above, is each increment of the number guaranteed, or not necessarily?

Comment: i see no reason why each execution should not increment it, the question is at which point you want to test it and if you want to keep it just `++` increment or actual things that need to be chained or ordered

Comment: Per my experience on this, you should have no worries. I have not experienced a problem

Comment: @johnSmith I was worried that there might have been some kind of race condition, but an answer below said that javascript doesn't do real multi threading and therefore all variable access stays synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript *is* always synchronous with itself.  This is not true multi-threading, which JS does not support or use.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wasn't completely sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can be sure of when and how often `someAsyncFunctionWithCallback` will run, there are no issues with this method. You only have to be aware of the fact that checking your variable at any given point will only reflect its current value based on how many times the callback has executed.

Answer (score 1):

Each callback `function(){ number++;}` will be called later in non-deterministic order to increase `number`. Only one thing can be assured here is N callback execution will increase N times the variable `number`

Comment: Great to know. Thanks!